# Processing command line arguments for a code in c++ for random and user input

Tags: c++, input, g++, command-line-arguments

Our instructor requires us to input data into code in the following ways:

> ```
> 1.Random mode
> Run with graphs generated by random number generator. The command line for 
> this mode is: 
> $ mst –r n d 
> // run in a random connected graph with n vertices and d% of density. 
> // See Performance measurements section for details. 
>
>
> 2.User Input mode
> $mst -s file-name // read the input from a file ‘file-name’ for simple scheme
> $mst -f file-name // read the input from a file ‘file-name’ for f-heap scheme
> ```

At present I have written the code and compiled it using g++:

```
g++ -o mst.o mst.cpp
```

I am taking input from the file like this:

```
./mst.o < data.txt
```

However, I don't know how to go about satisfying the above requirements.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to process the command-line arguments?

Comment: Yes that's the right way to say it.

Comment: Look into `getopt` or using a lightweight solution.

Comment: @remyabel: The command line looks a bit simple for that. With only three options just read the first argument (if it does not exist report error) then use `if () {} else if () {} else if () {} else {/*error*/}`. Note you can't switch on a string so you need else if :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An application starts in main like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

These are the command line arguments.

You can print them out if you want:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Application: " << argv[0] << "\n";
    for(int loop =1 ;loop < argc; ++loop)
    {
        std::cout << "\tArg: " << loop << "   Value: " << argv[loop] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the `argc` and `argv` parameters to `main`. If `argv` is large enough, check `argv[1]` to see if it's one of the switches you need to handle. If it is then decode the other `argv` for the numbers or filenames that you need. `argv[0]` is generally the name of the executable and isn't used.

Comment: What do you mean by large enough?

Comment: @nitinsh99: He means dont check `argv[x]` for a value where `x >= argc`